# How to switch focus from one textbox to another when we tap the tab button in WinRt apps?

Tags: winrt-async

In My WinRt apps,I need to tap twice on tab button for switch focus from one textbox to another. but i want to switch focus from one textbox to another in single tap on tab button. Please give me correct solution

Answer (score 0):

This works on my app :

```
  myTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
  myTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
  myTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, there is nothing to do to get the tab working.
If you need to press the TAB key twice, you are probably giving the focus to a control you do not expect because the tab order is not what you expect.

You can force the focus order by specifying the *TabIndex* property on your controls. In this way, you are sure about what will happen when pressing TAB.

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBox TabIndex="1" />
    <TextBox TabIndex="2" />
    <TextBox TabIndex="3" />
</StackPanel>
```